# Игнорируются битовые операции

Tags: typescript, битовые-операции

Хочу проверить, содержит ли строка корректное для int32 значение и пишу такой код:

```
function isInt32(val: string) {
  return val == (val as any | 0)
}
```

Однако тайпскрипт при его компиляции убирает битовую операцию:

```
function isInt32(val) {
    return val == val;
}
```

Попробовал с другими битовыми операциями - результат такой же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что в записи `val as any | 0` палка рассматривается не как битовая операция, а как часть типа: `val as (any | 0)`. Для того чтобы получить побитовое или, надо поставить скобки: `(val as any) | 0`.

После этого тайпскрипт не согласится со сравнением строки с числом, так что понадобится ещё у сравнения слева `any` поставить.

Вот код полностью:

```
function isInt32(val: string) {
  return val as any == ((val as any) | 0)
}
```

А ещё можно подумать о том, что этот код отлично работает и с числами и изменить функцию вот так:

```
function isInt32(val: string | number) {
  return val == ((val as any) | 0)
}
```

Comment: тогда в итоге лучше as number делать а не any. более логично будет

Comment: @Grundy, не согласен. Как программист, если я вижу запись `as number`, то ожидаю, что там действительно лежит число, просто ts об этом не в курсе. А в данном случае выражается именно намерение принудительно применить операция по принципу "я знаю, что тут сработает неявное приведение", поэтому затыкаем компилятор типом `any` - и он съедает, и программисту понятно, что тут не обязательно число. Ну и ещё в первом варианте `string` не приводится к `number` - у тебя будет `as any as number`.